# UPDATE query on field that has dynamic data mask

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, data-masking

I have this situation:

- A table in SQL Server 2016 has Dynamic Data masks configured on one column.
- I read one whole row into a front-end and display the values, including the masked field that returns value 'xxxx'
- To update the table, the application reads the values from the user front-end and generates an UPDATE SQL statement, that includes the 'xxxx' value for the masked field.
- SQL Server 2016 overwrites the existing value of the masked field with the value 'xxxx'.

Is there a way to configure SQL Server 2016 to understand that the value 'xxxx' is the masked value it just sent, and not overwrite the masked data?

Comment: Depends on encryption between application and sql

Comment: Can you please detail what you mean by that encryption? @BHouse

Comment: _front-end and display the values, including the masked field that returns value 'xxxx'_ - make front-end do not return masked value or on server side pass to the database only values you want to update.