# Validating dynamic data masked fields

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2016, data-masking

I've a situation similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179405/update-query-on-field-that-has-dynamic-data-mask) where I want the user to stop editing the fields (textboxes) in a form which is data bind to a database column and that column is having [Dynamic Data Masking (DDM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2016) applied.

I don't want to change each form and make the fields read only but instead want the common binding function to handle this automatically.

So basically the binding function will check the field is masked or not and make the field read only accordingly.

I know the below SQL query which returns the masked field which can be used to build a custom function.

```
SELECT tbl.name as table_name, c.name AS column_name, c.is_masked,     
c.masking_function  
FROM sys.masked_columns AS c  
JOIN sys.tables AS tbl ON c.object_id = tbl.object_id  
WHERE is_masked = 1;
```

Before doing that I want to make sure that there is no better method than that.

I was wondering if something similar like below exists.

```
((DataTable)dataSource).Columns[dataMember].Ismasked
```

Comment: _I don't want to change each form and make the fields read only_ - best option from user point of view. I want see that value is readonly.

Comment: I do want to make the fields read only but I don't want to change it in each form also when adding new forms I don't want to keep reminding me and others to make those fields read only. I want the common binding function to handle this automatically.

Comment: Write a code which will generate readonly cells in datagridview or generate others readonly controls based on the name of the column. Or even better create own `DataGridView`(which I assume you are using for displaying data), which will know how to handle masked values. Then use that control in all forms. Your logic will stay in one place - easy to maintain.

Comment: Okay that is what I planned to do however the question remains is, how do I check the column is masked or not in a more effective and performance oriented way.